# How to pull a response code into Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of URL's that I want to check the response code for. Does anyone know how I could do this in Google docs? I have 16000 url's so it's quite a big ask.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There is no builtin formula function to do this, but you can write one in [Google Apps Script](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/). Here is an example that you can adapt to your purpose.

```
function HTTPResponse( uri )
{
  var response_code ;
  try {
    response_code = UrlFetchApp .fetch( uri ) .getResponseCode() .toString() ;
  }
  catch( error ) {
    response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (\d\d\d)\./ )[1] ;
  }
  finally {
    return response_code ;
  }
}
```

Having defined this function, you can call it from a cell:

```
A1: 'http://www.google.com/
A2: = HTTPResponse( A1 )
```

A bug in `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` makes the string matching necessary. A fix was promised in the discussion thread *[UrlFetchApp.fetch - get response code on exception?](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/m_HOPHx64X8/discussion)*, but I cannot find that it was ever delivered. The workaround is dependent on the text of the exception message. That seems unreliable and dependent on locale.

Google's article *[Troubleshooting and Debugging Scripts](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/guide_troubleshooting.html)* warns that Google Apps Script imposes quotas on various actions. You might well find that 16,000 simultaneous HTTP requests will be throttled back. The article refers users having special needs to the [Google Apps Script Help Forum](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!forum/apps-script).

Comment: Official instructions of how to create a custom function: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function
Follow that, then simply copy paste the above script into the editor. Works great, thanks!

Comment: Here is a blog post with more detailed instructions that uses the above snippet: http://www.tinkeredge.com/blog/2012/04/check-on-page-for-broken-links-with-google-docs/

Comment: @MετάEd . How to apply the script for entire column of urls and time of status check in column C ? Furthermore, is there away to make the checking status every one hour for like 50 urls ?