# server response (header status) to google spreadsheet

Tags: redirect, google-apps-script

found this answer:
[How to pull a response code into Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522223/how-to-pull-a-response-code-into-google-spreadsheet/8581825#8581825)

which would solve my issue almost - but not fully.

instead of the simple status code (i.e. 301) i would need the full response code? i.e. if there is a 301 redirect, i'd like to know, the 301 redirection.

script above delivers: 301
i need 301 Moved Permanently http://www.mydomain/new-path

i found some infos here - but no way to implement the functions for my as marketeer.

Answer (score -1):

301 is the *full* response code. The redirect URL will be in the `Location` header of the response. I'll leave retrieving that as an exercise...